# Forwarding from a futures::Stream to a futures::Sink

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I am currently trying to wrap my head around the tokio & futures primitives and ecosystem.

I started doing some work from the [tk-http websockets example](https://github.com/swindon-rs/tk-http/blob/abfdb50a00ab90b4f01b23ff8dbefe6e83331d9c/examples/websockets.rs), and wanted to do more processing on the received data rather than echoing it back. A first step seemed to be to replace the .forward() call with some kind of loop.

It seemed to me that `stream.forward(sink)` is equivalent to `stream.fold(sink, |out_, item| { out.send(item).and_then(Sink::flush) })`, however doing this ([commit](https://gitlab.com/remram44/rs-web/commit/b1edd5a68ddb676b6a912576bdf08600cbeab96e)) the stream is not polled at all. However the same change from the Tokio example works fine ([example](https://gitlab.com/remram44/rs-web/commit/5345a3e7f5f4e4ec81791d5e7e0474154329bd0e)).

Furthermore, it seems that outputting something on the sink first makes the forwarding work fine ([commit](https://gitlab.com/remram44/rs-web/commit/d690039fde5d4d6ab35f0f0a13be3ef46c84807b)), so maybe the sink doesn't get registered with the event loop for some reason until a send happen? Did I miss something? Is it possible it is a bug in tk-http?

Comment: Can you put the relevant code parts of your problem into the question, as a [MCVE]? Having to check code from links is not very readable and makes it harder to answer.

Comment: Not easily since you do need client code along with it, to make the websocket connection. I'll see if I can minimalize it a bit...

Comment: You might find some answers in [this example](https://github.com/cyderize/rust-websocket/blob/master/examples/parallel-server.rs) that I wrote myself, as I had similar troubles. The indentation is jumbled up because the project uses an old version of rustfmt, I recommend copy-pasting it into your own editor and running the latest rustfmt on it.

Comment: Are you sure the "flush" isn't the difference here? `.forward()` is definitely equivalent to `.fold(sink, |out, b| { out.send(b) })`, but it doesn't call `flush` like your fold example. Could it just be that for your application, you need to flush the stream, and thus `forward` is not appropriate?