# Splitting a futures::Stream into multiple streams based on a property of the stream item

Tags: stream, rust

I have a `Stream` of items `(u32, Bytes)` where the integer is an index in the range `0..n` I would like to split this stream into `n` streams, basically filtering by the integer.

I considered several possibilities, including

- creating `n` streams each of which peeks at the underlying stream to determine if the next item is for it
- pushing the items to one of `n` sinks when they arrive, and then use the other side of the sink as a stream again. (This seems to be related to 
  [Forwarding from a futures::Stream to a futures::Sink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44990227/forwarding-from-a-futuresstream-to-a-futuressink).).

I feel that neither of these possibilities is convincing. The first one seems to create unnecessary overhead and the second one is just not elegant (if it even works, I am not sure).

What's a good way of splitting the stream?

Answer (score 3):

At one point I had a similar requirement and wrote a `group_by` operator for `Stream`.

I haven't yet published this to crates.io as I didn't really feel it was ready for consumption but feel free to take a look at the code at https://github.com/Lukazoid/lz_stream_tools or attempt to use it for yourself.

Add the following to your cargo.toml:

```
[dependencies]
lz_stream_tools = { git = "https://github.com/Lukazoid/lz_stream_tools" }
```

And `extern crate lz_stream_tools;` to your bin.rs/lib.rs.

Then from your code you may use it like so:

```
use lz_stream_tools::StreamTools;

let groups = some_stream.group_by(|x| x.0);
```

`groups` will now be a `Stream` of `(u32, Stream<Item=Bytes))`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [channels](http://alexcrichton.com/futures-rs/futures/sync/mpsc/index.html) to represent the index-specific streams. You'd have to spawn one `Task` that pulls from the original stream and has a map of `Sender`s.

Comment: How is pushing to n channels instead of n sinks any different? (channels *are* a sink implementation.) Also the link is dead